# Complexity $\text{O}\left(\log(\log n))^{10}\right)$ vs $\text{O}\left((\log(\log n))^5\right)$?

Tags: algorithms, logarithms, asymptotics

If the question is not clear, then assume $t=\log(\log n)$, then the question can be re-framed as $\text{O}(t^{10})$ vs $O(t^5)$? So which has a higher order of growth?

Thanks.

Comment: Some notes: please use MathJax for math expressions. It is highly recommended to share some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$t$ goes to infinity, though slowly.

Therefore
$t^{10}$ grows faster than
$t^5$.